# Can Cosine similarity be used for non-textual Data (or more precisely numeric or categorical data)?

Tags: python-3.x, similarity, cosine-similarity

As cosine similarity works on vectors, I want to know, if it can be used get similarity between numeric or categorical data?

For example:
A data of customers shopping from supermarket has only categorical or numerical values

```
CustID  Gender  online  milk    bread   egg diapers  
234        1    1        0        1     1     0
235        2    1        0        1     0     0
234        1    0        1        0     0     1
234        1    0        0        1     0     1
238        3    0        0        0     0     0
239        1    0        1        1     0     1
240        2    1        0        0     1     1
```

Gender is categorical and rest variable are int64.

How can I use cosine similarity to see the similarity between the data (specifically, similarity between shopping of a single customer as there are multiple entry of a single customer)?
Also, which other similarity method I should use?

Answer (score 0):

Cosine similarity is used for categorical data.

```
# download scratch package if it's not installed on compute
# pip3 install scratch
from scratch.linear_algebra import dot, Vector

def cosine_similarity(vec1: Vector, vec2: Vector) -> float:
    return dot(vec1, vec2) / (dot(vec1, vec1) * dot(vec2, vec2))**0.5
```

Comment: This question is bit late. But I wasn't able to understand what "Cosine similarity is used for categorical data." means. Can we not use for only numerical data?